# How can I delete some text from inside of a file?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a text file with the following contents:

```
3,3,5,7,9,10,1
```

I can read the file and reach the content by `ReadToEnd()` method, but I want to delete only '3', so that it has the contents:

```
5,7,9,10,10
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What does this have to do with Notepad?

Comment: @SebastianPaaskeTørholm edited to make (I hope) more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete it from with in Notepad, try find & replacing `3,` with and empty space. If you are doing it from within you program you have to parse the file and make a new one only appending it with the values you want